# Why do privileges in BH.SE still have the level of a public beta site?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Points for [privileges in BH.SE](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) require only about 20% compared to what seems to be the standard thresholds such as in [C.SE](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), [SciFi.SE](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges), [StackOverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), or [SuperUser.com](https://superuser.com/help/privileges).

For example, to access moderator tools, one needs only 2,000 points in BH.SE, not the typical 10,000 points in other sites.

Tiago Martins Peres alerted me to a [meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58587/364217) which shows that the current privilege points are aligned with those of a **public beta** site.

So the question becomes: was it a mistake that the threshold wasn't adjusted to a graduated site when BH.SE launched on Aug 1, 2019?  If it was NOT a mistake, what was the reason to let the threshold remain at the level of a public beta site?

Comment: Hi GratefulDisciple. You might want to read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58587/364217)

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres李大仁 Thanks.  So it looks like BH.SE is aligned with a Public Beta threshold.  But the site has graduated since Aug 1, 2019.  Was it a mistake that the threshold wasn't adjusted to a graduated site?

Comment: @GratefulDisciple It's "graduated" in that the beta label was removed, but most other things remain. We could request the rep points to be increased, if we thought it would help? But I don't know if it would. It doesn't feel like, for example, we have too many new users who get close/reopen privileges before they become aware of the site standards.

Comment: @curiousdannii I was just curious.  I would also let the rep stands until there is a good reason to change it.